# Webpack lazy load modules from isomorphic components (shared code between server & client side)

Tags: javascript, node.js, webpack, babeljs

Lets say I have a node express server and a client side JavaScript App.

Both share the same components.

The client side javascript is bundled via webpack.

Naturally there are some libraries only needed on the client side.

The problem is how do I configure webpack to lazyload those modules.

When I only had a Client Side App I used this within a function that would only be called on the client side:

```
await import( /* webpackChunkName: "tinymce" */ 'tinymce' );
```

Together with using the `chunkFilename:` option within webpacks output directive this caused the module only to be loaded on request.

Unfortunately this doesn't work when running the code with node, as the import method is not available.

If I now use the node equivalent require call inside a function instead:

```
require( 'tinymce' );
```

Webpack includes the whole dependency within the entry point and doesn't splits the chunk any longer.

**How Can I use lazy loading of modules when sharing the codebase between the server and clientside without having to transpile node code as well?**

Comment: https://medium.com/airbnb-engineering/server-rendering-code-splitting-and-lazy-loading-with-react-router-v4-bfe596a6af70

Comment: @Dominic thanks for the comment, doesn't really solve the challange though. I mean it might, but I would have to setup a second transpile step for the server side code as well so that I can use the async `imports` instead of `requires`. Currently I am only transpiling for the client side but leave the server side code untouched. I might decide to do this if I can't do it otherwise

Comment: es6 imports don't work in node outside of .mjs files, you would need to transpile. Or possibly rename all your files to mjs and handle those on the UI instead (but note that many cloud providers only support Node 8 in standard environments).

Answer (score 0):

Its possible to reuse the same code within node and on the clientside without having to transpile the server side code.

It works by using `require.ensure()` instead of only `require()`:

```
// Returns a promise that resolves with the Module
require.ensure( [], ( require ) => require( 'pikaday' ) )
```

Node won't complain and if you are defining a `chunkFilename` within your `webpack.config.js` `output` directive, webpack will successfully put the module into its own file that will be loaded when necessary.

I have only tested this with modules that I only need on the clientside and called them conditionally by checking if `typeof document === 'object'` as `require.ensure` is actually not a standard method but webpack specific. So it probably **won't work if you need a module on both the client side and server side**, although you could try using a polyfill for require.ensure for node.